# how to show different panel on the center of the window based on button click event extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member

I am having some problems in displaying different panel on the center area of border layout window.

Consider I am having border layout window with east side containing different button, which on click will display the grid on the center of the layout window.

my window is shown below with east containing buttons and center is empty.
[image]

**my updated controller code is given below**

```
Ext.define('rms.controller.companymgt.CompanyMgtController',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

stores:['companyStore'],
models:['companyModel'],
views: [
        'companymgt.companyMain',
        'companymgt.companyView',
        'companymgt.companyDetail',
        'companymgt.companyAdd',
        'companymgt.fileUpload'
        ,'companymgt.departmentDetail',
        'companymgt.designationDetail',
        'companymgt.groupDetail'
        ],

refs: [{
    ref: 'companyMain',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: 'companymain',
    xtype: 'companymain'
},{
    ref: 'companyAdd',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: 'companyadd',
    xtype: 'companyadd'
},{
    ref: 'fileUpload',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: 'fileupload',
    xtype: 'fileupload'
},{
    ref: 'departmentDetail',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: '#departmentdetail',
    xtype: 'departmentdetail'
},{
    ref: 'designationDetail',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: '#designationdetail',
    xtype: 'designationdetail'
},{
    ref: 'groupDetail',
    autoCreate: true,
    selector: '#groupdetail',
    xtype: 'groupdetail'
},{
    ref: 'companyDetail',
    autCreate: true,
    selector: '#companydetail',
    xtype: 'companydetail'
}],

init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#companyview button[action=company-view]': {
            click: this.createCompanyview
        },
        '#companyview button[action=department-view]': {
            click: this.createDepartmentview
        },
        '#companyview button[action=designation-view]': {
            click: this.createDesignationview
        },
        '#companyview button[action=group-view]': {
            click: this.createGroupview
        },      
        '#companyview button[action=file-view]': {
            click: this.createFilemgtview
        },

        '#companydetailtoolbar #mnuDept': {
            click: this.createDepartmentnew
        },
        '#companydetailtoolbar #mnuExcel': {
            click: this.exportExcel
        },
        '#companydetailtoolbar #mnuCSV': {
            click: this.exportCSV
        }
    });
},

createCompanyview: function(btn) {
    alert('company view clicked');
},

createDepartmentview: function(btn) {
    alert('department view clicked');
    var departmentCard = this.getDepartmentDetail();
    var mainComp = this.getCompanyMain();
    mainComp.getLayout().setActiveItem('departmentCard');
},

createDesignationview: function(btn) {
    alert('designation view clicked');
},

createGroupview: function(btn) {
    alert('group view clicked');
},

createFilemgtview: function(btn) {
    alert('FILE MGT WINDOW');
    this.getFileUpload().show();
},

createDepartmentnew: function(obj) {
    this.getCompanyAdd().show();
}
```

});

**my main view code is given below**

```
Ext.define('rms.view.companymgt.companyMain', {
    extend: 'rms.model.desktopmgt.Module',
    alias: 'widget.companymain',
    requires: ['rms.view.companymgt.companyView','rms.view.companymgt.companyDetail'],
    id: 'companymain',

    init: function() {
        this.launcher = {
                text: 'Company Management System',
                iconCls: 'project-mini-icon',
                handler: this.createWindow,
                scope: this
        };
    },

    createWindow: function() {
        var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
        var win = desktop.getWindow('companymgt-win');
        if(!win){
            win = desktop.createWindow({
                id: 'companymgt-win',
                title: 'Company Management System',
                height: 566,
                width: 900,
                layout: 'border',
                constrain: true,
                modal: true,
                closeAction: 'destroy',
                items: [{
                    region: 'west',
                    collapsible: true,
                    //html: 'MAIN VIEW',
                    xtype: 'companyview',
                    flext:1
                },{
                    region: 'center',
                    collapsible: true,
                    //html: 'DETAIL VIEW',
                    xtype: 'companydetail',
                    flex:3
                }]
            });
        }
        win.show();
        return win.setPosition(100,100);
    }
});
```

**when the company button is clicked I get the alert window.**

But based on the button click I want to open different detail view to the center layout of the window.

Please suggest me some solution, so I can view different window on the border layout of the window as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a card layout.  The easiest thing would be to give each component an `itemId`.  Then in your controller you would have:

```
, refs: [
  {
    ref: 'mainCardComponent'
    , selector: '#mainCardComponent'
  },
  {
    ref: 'companyCard'
    , selector: '#companyCard'
  },
  {
    ref: 'departmentCard'
    , selector: '#departmentCard'
  }...
```

Then you can reference using `get...` within the scope of your controller like:

```
var companyCard = this.getCompanyCard();
```

To swap out the cards, you would do something like:

```
var mainComp = this.getMainCardComponent();
mainComp.getLayout().setActiveItem('companyCard');
```

Comment: thanks for your response I had made the necessary changes as per you said. But it didn't seems to be working. I had added my controller as well as my view code above. Please suggest me how can I get it done

Comment: I see you aren't using "itemId" but you are trying to access with selector: '#companydetail".  The "#" is only for referencing components for which you have set "itemId".  If you have set up an alias (like you did with companyMain), then you don't need the "#", just use selector: 'companydetail'.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make center piece a container and remove old/add new stuff to it when needed.
2. If you have limited number of content pages make center piece layout 'card' and create all pages at once. Only one will be visible. You can change visibility when user click certain button.